# xamarin forms: On or off the listview switch based on a condition?

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have a listview with a switch, like below screenshot.

[image]

**string userIds = Application.Current.Properties["GroupUserIds"].ToString();** (userIds is a comma separated string)
I need to on the switch item if the id of switch item exists in the above string(userIds).

For example, if the id of Vimal Mathew is 120 and the value of userIds = 181,481,476,120,132(120 exists in userIds). Then the switch for Vimal Mathew should be in on state and other list items switches should in off state those are not in userids string.

I tried like below:

**Binding the userId and calling a converter.**

```
  <Switch
         Toggled="OnToggledEvent"
         IsToggled="{Binding userProfileTO.userId,  Converter={StaticResource userIdExistConverter}}"
         HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

**In the converter form a list from the userIds by splitting with the comma and checking the userid is exist in the list. If userid exist in the list return true and not exists return false.**

My converter code:

```
class UserIdExistConverter : IValueConverter
 {
#region IValueConverter implementation
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return string.Empty;

        bool exist = false;
        string userIds = Application.Current.Properties["GroupUserIds"].ToString();
        List<string> userIdList = userIds.Split(',').ToList();
        Debug.WriteLine("listcount:>>" + userIdList.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < userIdList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == userIdList[i])
            {
                exist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    return exist;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
#endregion
}
}
```

**But getting Unhandled Exception: System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.**

I am not using any viewmodel here. I am doing a feature like a group in whatsapp, string userIds contains the current group member ids, so when I search for adding a new member, the already added members switch should be in on state.

**Bool method that returns true if id exist in the group and false if not exist in the group.**

```
bool IsUserInList(int userId)
{
string userIds = Application.Current.Properties["GroupUserIds"].ToString();
List<int> userIdList = userIds.Split(",").Select(id => int.Parse(id)).ToList();
return userIdList.Contains(userId);
}
```

I don't know my logic is correct, please put some light on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You try to bind your toggled to probably a string, so what should happen in your Viewmodel (i assume you use mvvm) if the switch was toggled by the user? Your problem is, that you didn't implement `ConvertBack` as the exception already says...

Comment: I am not using viewmodel. I am doing a feature like a group in whatsapp, string userIds contains the current group member ids, so when I search for adding a new member, the already added members switch should be in on state.

Comment: Yeah okay, but what if your user now toggles one of the switches, your isToggled value is bound to a string but is a boolean, what do you think happens?!
You should not write a converter but mabye use a wrapper around your person class with a property called `IsInGroup` (Bool) or something and bind this value to isToggled

Comment: I can write a method which returns true or false based on that member exist or not in the group. But how I can merge the method response to isToggled property?

I added a bool method to question.

Answer (score 0):

I would ditch that converter altogether and go a more viewmodel-centric way. Your page has a viewmodel and the cells have, too. The viewmodels associated with the cells have a property `Selected` that is set or unset, based on the values present in the list of users.

```
class UsersPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> Users
    {
        get => this.users;

        set
        {
            if(value == this.users)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.users = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string UserIds 
    {
        get => this.userIds;

        set 
        {
            this.userIds = value;
            UpdateUsers();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateUsers()
    {
        var userIds = this.UserIds.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray(); // add error handling

        foreach(var user in Users)
        {
            user.Selected = userIds.Contains(user.Id);
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string callerName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(callerName));
    }
}
```

The `UserViewModel` is quite straightforward

```
class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    User user;

    public UserViewModel(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public bool Selected
    {
        get => this.selected;

        set
        {
            if(selected == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            selected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Id => this.user.Id;

    // OnPropertyChanged is implemented the same way
    // add more properties as you need them
}
```

Your XAML does not have to care about the logic, but only about how to represent the vms this way. Please note that I have omitted the code to load the users and the list of selected users. I think that gap can be easily filled by you.

Comment: Yeah, but you have more control over what is happening when and which methods are called with this approach. And you are setting the `Selected` property directly, instead of converting it with the converter.

Comment: I told him to not use a converter.  I think the problem lies a bit deeper, I think he doesn't really understand how the two way binding of the IsToggled works...

Comment: @Johanned, ah, now I got it, I just skimmed the answers and thought it was him answering again. D'oh! :)